# SMPP connect to server and send with GSM

Tags: sql, sql-server, gsm, smpp

GoodDay Masters,

I want to know what is the configuration on how to connect SMPP into my server, I want my SMPP automatically reply on the text message on what subscriber what to know.

example:

subscriber A text **Trucker ABC 123** then SMPP reply **Driver Uncle Sam**

Subs text the plate number of the truck then SMPP will query the plate number on the database(MSSQL 2005) then reply the name of the driver using a GSM modem.

Anyone can give me at least a brief Introduction on how to handle this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMPP is a protocol for sending and receiving large numbers of SMSs.

You can rent space on an SMS Gateway server attached to your mobile operator's network, which will have an SMPP interface.  You get a mobile number, to which your subscribers can send their messages.

Then you need to have your own server program to receive the SMSs in SMPP format; query your database; build a reply SMS and send it back to the gateway in SMPP format.

The SMPP is explained on [Wikipedia here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Peer-to-Peer)
At the bottom of the page are links to the latest versions of the SMPP spec.

Comment: @S List can you give a sample query that can connect to database using SMPP interface.. thanks!

Comment: SMPP is not a database interface.  Query your database, then use the result as input to build the SMPP message, and send it to the SMS gateway.